# Design Mode not working

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have created a brand new Juno installation and installed the Worklight plugin.

When I drag a control (e.g. Submit Button) to the Design pane, I get
the + but when I drop it, nothing appears!

Any ideas?

Op sys = Vista

Eclipse = Juno Service Relaease 1 Build id: 20120920-0800

Worklight Version: 5.0.6100.201304160150

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in Worklight 5.0.6.1

1. Created a new Worklight project
2. Added an application
3. Added the Palette view
4. Switched to Design view for the HTML file
5. Dragged a Submit Button from the palette view to the Design view
6. An actual button with the "Submit" lable appeared

So, please edit your question with your Worklight version, Operating system, etc...

Comment: Question updated. Like I say it is a brand new installation and it LOOKS like it is going to work, but nothing happens when I drop an object in the design view. Is there any trace I can turn on to help debug this?